# Application Request Routing IIS load balancing HTTPS setup causing 301 redirect

Tags: ssl, iis, load-balancing, arr

I have setup load balancing server with Application request routing on IIS, it's working fine but I am facing issue with https requests, they are being redirect(301) and in post call it's losing the post data.

I have disabled SSL offloading but still the https post requests are failing and taking me to login page due to post data not being forwarded to ARR or something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for now, I have added * binding and that seems to be working, not sure why it doesn't work when I specify the domain name in binding. but it's sorted by problem so good for now, but will be better to know how it will work with domain name in the binding.